# Accessing JBoss Cache deployed on a remote JBoss AS (4.2.2)

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-cache

I have deployed the JBoss cahce service to my JBoss AS which is running remotely in a completely separate VM. I am now struggling to access the cache deployed to the AS. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

[TcpCacheLoader](http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5.0.0/html/Cache_User_Guide/ch02s08.html) can be used to access remote caches. For more details, checkout [Chapter 9, Cache Loaders](http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5.0.0/html/Cache_User_Guide/cache_loaders.html). I think that you'll need to set up [hierarchical caches](http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5.0.0/html/Cache_User_Guide/ch09s05s05.html) using the [`TcpDelegatingCacheLoader`](http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5.0.0/html/Cache_User_Guide/cl.tcp.html).